# fastboot getvar from batch file

Tags: android, batch-file, command-line, fastboot

I was trying to get certain fastboot variables from a batch file. I was using something like :

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('fastboot.exe getvar version-bootloader') do @echo version is %%a
```

But I get the output on command line, not in the variable %%a. the command 'fastboot.exe getvar version-bootloader' works perfectly in command-line. I also tried doing:

```
fastboot.exe getvar version-bootloader >> temp.txt
```

but temp.txt is always empty and i receive the output on the command line, instead of the file. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: It seems that `fastboot.exe` don't use the stdout stream. You could try to redirect stream2. `fastboot.exe getvar version-bootloader 2> temp.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fastboot output is directed to error stream, you can direct error stream to standard stream by adding `2>&1`

1. your script will get two lines since fastboot getvar returns additional line with time elapsed.
2. your script parses the version with a leading space, you shoud add a space to the delimiter (it is default but when you give delims it is overwritten)

you should use:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('fastboot.exe getvar version-bootloader 2^>^&1 ^| findstr version') do @echo version is %%a
```

Comment: Although jeb's comment did the job, your comment allowed me to parse the response. Thnx